# find out if date with added interval of days lies in week

Tags: t-sql, date, sql-server-2012, intervals

Making it simple, I've got the following definitions:

```
DECLARE @referenceDate DATETIME
SET @referenceDate = '20171123';
DECLARE @intervalDays INT
SET @intervalDays = 30
DECLARE @weekMonday DATETIME
SET @weekMonday = '20171204';
DECLARE @weekSunday DATETIME
SET @weekSunday = '20171210';
```

Something important is happening at exactly these dates:

```
@referenceDate
DATEADD(day, 1 * @intervalDays, @referenceDate);
DATEADD(day, 2 * @intervalDays, @referenceDate);
DATEADD(day, 3 * @intervalDays, @referenceDate);
```

and so on.

I want to find out if this 'something important' will (also) happen in the specified week between @weekMonday and @weekSunday.

I've got SQL Server version 11.0.6251.0 Standard Edition, German localization. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found this solution with modulo:

```
IF (DATEDIFF(day, @referenceDate, @weekMonday) % @intervalDays = 0 OR
    DATEDIFF(day, @referenceDate, DATEADD(day, 1, @weekMonday)) % @intervalDays = 0 OR
    DATEDIFF(day, @referenceDate, DATEADD(day, 2, @weekMonday)) % @intervalDays = 0 OR
    DATEDIFF(day, @referenceDate, DATEADD(day, 3, @weekMonday)) % @intervalDays = 0 OR
    DATEDIFF(day, @referenceDate, DATEADD(day, 4, @weekMonday)) % @intervalDays = 0 OR
    DATEDIFF(day, @referenceDate, DATEADD(day, 5, @weekMonday)) % @intervalDays = 0 OR
    DATEDIFF(day, @referenceDate, DATEADD(day, 6, @weekMonday)) % @intervalDays = 0)
   SELECT @monday AS found
```

Maybe someone knows how to further simplify it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am unclear exactly what you are looking for.

If in range:

```
DECLARE @referenceDate DATETIME
SET @referenceDate = '20171123';
DECLARE @intervalDays INT
SET @intervalDays = 30
DECLARE @weekMonday DATETIME
SET @weekMonday = '20171204';
DECLARE @weekSunday DATETIME
SET @weekSunday = '20171210';

SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN DATEADD(day, @intervalDays, @referenceDate) BETWEEN @weekMonday AND @weekSunday 
            THEN @intervalDays
        WHEN DATEADD(day, @intervalDays + 30, @referenceDate) BETWEEN @weekMonday AND @weekSunday 
            THEN @intervalDays + 30 
        ELSE 0 
    END AS [IsReferenceDatePlusIntervalDaysWithinTheDateRange]
```

How many days until range:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, @referenceDate, @weekMonday) AS [NumberOfDaysBetweenReferenceDateToWeekMonday]
```

Comment: The first code snippet finds out if "referenceDate + 30 days" lies in the specified week. But I need to also find out if "referenceDate + 60 days" or "referenceDate + 90 days" and so on lies in the specified week. It seems to me that's only possible with a loop, but is this true?

Comment: Are the intervals predefined, or are they arbitrary? You can do several checks in one query, but you have to be able to define the checks, so to speak.

Comment: Maybe it will work with modulo somehow like this: DATEDIFF(day, referenceDate, weekMonday) % intervalDays = 0  but I must check this for every day of the week....

Comment: The interval is predefined for every referenceDate and does not change.